# Laravel Eloquen add additional element in table insertion using model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am getting the Registration Details by `$RegisterData = Input::all();` and after the validation rules i am creating it by `RiderModel::create($RegisterData);` by in the middle i want to generate a random number and store along with it

i.e., $RegisterData ->Code = $generatedrandomnumber;

How can i do this in eloquent itself

Comment: Depending what your random number column is called you can use the `array_merge` method like so; `RiderModel::create(array_merge(array('rand_col_name' => $generatedrandomnumber), $RegisterData));`

Comment: But the coloumn is not getting inserted with the generated `$generatedrandomnumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using `creating` event:

```
// RiderModel
public static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  static::creating(function ($rider) {
    $rider->code = $rider->code ?: YOUR_RANDOM_NO_FUNCTION();
  });
}
```

then you don't need to change your code at all:

```
RiderModel::create($RegisterData);
```

If no `code` is passed along with the input, then it will be appended to the model during creating.

Answer (score 1):

what about the fill() method? 
Fill() fills all the data from an array to your fillable fields which are declared in your RiderModel Model.

```
class RiderModel extends Eloquent{
    # Fillable Fields
    protected $fillable = array('foo', 'bar');
    ....
}
```

after you had filled your model with your fillable attributes you can store your code into the model and then save it:

```
 $riderModel = new RiderModel;
 $riderModel->fill(Input::all());
 $riderModel->code = $generatedrandomnumber;
 $riderModel->save();
```